# How to add array duplicate value to a single value

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array..

[image]

you can see 0 and 2 array index has same year and make value so i want it in a single and also check if array already have same year and make name then model value will be added only single.

My code..

```
<?php
            global $wpdb;
            $get_make_result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_make_details` WHERE `post_id` = ".$post_id."");
    /*      echo "<pre>";
            print_r($get_make_result);
*/


            if(isset($get_make_result)){

             ?>
                <h3 id="head_mmy">Selected Make, Year and Model List.</h3>
                <table class="child_class_make">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="hedi">Make</th>
                        <th class="hedi">Year</th>
                        <th class="hedi">Model</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <?php


                        $results = array();
                        foreach ($get_make_result as $k => $val_make) {
                                  $results[implode($val_make)] = $val_make;

                            $str = preg_replace('/(?<!\d),|,(?!\d{3})/', ', ', $val_make->model_name);
                    ?>
                            <td><?php echo $val_make->make_name; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $val_make->year; ?></td>

                            <td><textarea id="text_model" rows="4" cols="30"><?php echo $str;?></textarea></td>
                    <? }
                    $results = array_values($results);
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($results);
                } ?>
```

output like

```
(
    [c_id] => ..
    [post_id] => 15563
    [make_name] => Zero
    [year] => 2017
    [model_name] => S,SR,DSR,DS,FX,FXS
)
```

Comment: [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter)?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$results = array();

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
  $results[implode((array)$v)] = $v;
}

$results = array_values($results);
print_r($results);
```

DEMO

https://ideone.com/rJZRea

Comment: convert your object to array

Comment: can you post your array variable so that i can test for that

Comment: i have made a little change to answer try this

Comment: `implode((array)$v)`

Answer (score 0):

Using a Loop, you can bundle data with similar values (Duplicates) together: [Quick-Test Here:](https://eval.in/667619)

```
<?php

    function sortByNameYear($arr){
        $return = $result = [];
        foreach($arr as $key=>&$val){
            if(!array_key_exists($val->year, $result)){
                $result[$val->year] = [];
                if(!array_key_exists($val->make_name, $result[$val->year])){
                    $result[$val->year][$val->make_name] = [];
                }
            }
            $result[$val->year][$val->make_name][] = $val;
        }

        foreach($result as $year=>&$arrMake){
            foreach($arrMake as $iKey=>&$arrData){
                foreach($arrData as $iK=>$data){
                    if(count($arrData)>1) {
                        $tmp                    = $arrData[0];
                        if($iK !=0){
                            $tmp->c_id          = $arrData[0]->c_id . ", " . $data->c_id;
                            $tmp->post_id       = $arrData[0]->post_id . ", " . $data->post_id;
                            $tmp->model_name    = $arrData[0]->model_name . ", " . $data->model_name;
                            $return[]           = $tmp;
                        }
                    }else{
                        $return[]               = $data;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }

    var_dump(sortByNameYear($arr));
```

The `var_dump(sortByNameYear($arr))` above yields something like:

```
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public 'c_id' => string '89, 78' (length=6)
          public 'post_id' => string '15563, 15563' (length=12)
          public 'make_name' => string 'Zero' (length=4)
          public 'year' => string '2017' (length=4)
          public 'model_name' => string 'S, SR, DSR, DS, FX, FXS, SR, DS' (length=31)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[2]
          public 'c_id' => int 90
          public 'post_id' => int 15563
          public 'make_name' => string 'Yamaha' (length=6)
          public 'year' => string '2015' (length=4)
          public 'model_name' => string 'YZF-RIM, YZF-R3, FZ-09, FXZ-012' (length=31)
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[6]
          public 'c_id' => string '80' (length=6)
          public 'post_id' => int 15563
          public 'make_name' => string 'Zero' (length=4)
          public 'year' => string '2015' (length=4)
          public 'model_name' => string 'S, SR' (length=5)
      3 => 
        object(stdClass)[5]
          public 'c_id' => int 79
          public 'post_id' => int 15563
          public 'make_name' => string 'Yamaha' (length=6)
          public 'year' => string '1999' (length=4)
          public 'model_name' => string 'TTR250L' (length=7)
```